# Access property in div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to access the transform in this div `<div id="slideShow3" class="slideShow" style="width: 490px; height: 490px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px; transform: rotate(-10.9956rad);">` , it's there instead of inside css because the value is edited by a template.

I have tried `$('#slideShow3').attr('transform');` doesn't work.

Same problem when I try to get the `z-index` from this li `<li style="z-index: 100;">
<img width="100%" alt="Fish" src="/media/cache/95/2d/952d083ec4919a006ad6666680ea322c.jpg" style="transform: rotate(-32.9867rad);">
</li>`

Comment: transform is not an attribute. It is part of the style attribute....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `.attr` because it's not an attribute.

`style` is the attribute.

Try accessing the css method to get the style you want. Like this:

```
$('#slideShow3').css('transform');
$('#slideShow3').css('z-index');
```

And if you need to set some css you can add a second parameter to the css function like this

```
$('#slideShow3').css('z-index', 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `css` instead of `attr`, it works like attr, but for the properties inside style atribute:

```
$('#slideShow3').css('transform');
```